# Doctrine2: testing repository classes with YAML config

Tags: testing, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have YAML config for my symfony2 project using Doctrine2. I'm not understanding how exactly to adapt the [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html#setup) to a YAML setup.

My doctrine mapping is at `/path/to/my/bundle/Resources/config/doctrine/IpRange.orm.yml`

When running PHPUnit, I get the error:

Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: No mapping file found named 'Yitznewton.FreermsBundle.Entity.IpRange.orm.yml' for class 'Yitznewton\FreermsBundle\Entity\IpRange'.

Sounds like I need to configure the test rig to use the symfony file naming conventions, but I don't know how to do that.

Using symfony-standard.git checked out to v2.0.7

Here's my test:

```
<?php

namespace Yitznewton\FreermsBundle\Tests\Utility;

use Doctrine\Tests\OrmTestCase;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver;
use Yitznewton\FreermsBundle\Entity\IpRange;
use Yitznewton\FreermsBundle\Entity\IpRangeRepository;

class IpRangeRepositoryTest extends OrmTestCase
{
    private $_em;

    protected function setup()
    {
        // FIXME: make this path relative
        $metadataDriver = new YamlDriver('/var/www/symfony_2/src/Yitznewton/FreermsBundle/Resources/config/doctrine');
        $metadataDriver->setFileExtension('.orm.yml');

        $this->_em = $this->_getTestEntityManager();
        $this->_em->getConfiguration()
            ->setMetadataDriverImpl($metadataDriver);

        $this->_em->getConfiguration()->setEntityNamespaces(array(
            'FreermsBundle' => 'Yitznewton\\FreermsBundle\\Entity'));
    }

    protected function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->_em->getRepository('FreermsBundle:IpRange');
    }

    public function testFindIntersecting_RangeWithin_ReturnsIpRange()
    {
        $ipRange = new IpRange();
        $ipRange->setStartIp('192.150.1.1');
        $ipRange->setEndIp('192.160.1.1');

        $this->assertEquals(1, count($this->getRepository()
            ->findIntersecting($ipRange)),
            'some message');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking again at the symfony docs, it seems that integration testing with a live test database is preferred to unit testing for repository classes. That is, there is no support for stubbing EntityManagers.